# Confirmation box before submitting

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

I have this form, which i need to modify in order to confirm it before submission.

```
 echo '<form method="post" action="coupon.php">
<input type="hidden" name="id_user"
 value="'.$id_user.'">
 <input type="hidden" name="points"
 value="250">
 <input type="hidden" name="form_secret" id="form_secret" value="'.$_SESSION['FORM_SECRET'].'" />
  <div id="p2">
<input type="submit" value="250"></div>
</form>';
```

I tried to implement many jquery modal boxes (i don't need plain javascript because i need to add some design) but the form even if there was a popup continued to process.
Can you suggest me something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my approach to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="blah.php" class="confirm" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="field1" value="" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div class="modal" style="display: none;">
            <h1>Attention!!</h1>
            <p>Please confirm this action</p>
            <button type="button" class="action confirm">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="action cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <script>
        $(function(){
            // capture the form that triggered the action
            var $form;
            // can the form submit
            var $cansend = false;

            // show the modal on form submit
            $('form.confirm').submit(function(){
                $form = $(this);
                if ($cansend == true)
                {
                    $cansend = false;
                    return true;
                }
                $('.modal').show();
                return false;
            });

            // which button got clicked in the modal
            $('div.modal button.action').click(function(){
                if ($(this).hasClass('confirm'))
                {
                    $cansend = true;
                    $('div.modal').hide();
                    $form.submit();
                }
                else
                {
                    $cansend = false;
                    $('div.modal').hide();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this one, thanks for bothering :)
The issue is i still don't get any popup!
can it be because i got 4 forms in my page?
Thanks!

Comment: @al_alb I've added a class of confirm the form, so it only fires on forms with a class of confirm, the modal has a class of modal if you want to style it

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple javascript in order to make confirm box.
Inside  use onclick/onsubmit="createConfirm()" />

Then use javascript confirm box to display confirm box on submission of answer.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp
use this link will give you the example of confirm box.

You can also modify the layout. you can have a look at that. This would be useful.
http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/dialog/#default

Comment: Thanks, but if i do it this way i can't modify the layout!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your form tag....

```
onsubmit="return false"

echo '<form method="post" action="coupon.php" onsubmit="return false" id="formID">
```

show  the conformation popup...

and on confirm.... post the form...

```
if(CONFORMATION){    
  $('#formID').submit() ;  
}else{
  //do your stuff
}
```

**OR**

```
 $("form").submit(function() {
   //show your conformation popup

   if(CONFORMATION){
     return true;
   }

   return false;
});
```

this needs nothing on your `<form>` tag